# Keep receiving query error in Flex Viewer for Search Widget in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, query, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am not sure what is going wrong, but I keep receiving this query error https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAAK7.png

Here are the settings for the search widget

```
     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <zoomscale>50000</zoomscale>
    <shareresults>false</shareresults>
    <layers>
        <layer>
            <name>Lumos Fiber</name>
            <url>http://vdi-standard103.lumosnet.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Type2CircuitsOffNet/AllType2MapCircuitsOffNet/MapServer/11</url>
            <expression>FiberRingID.RingName LIKE upper('%[value]%')</expression>
            <textsearchlabel>Type in Ring ID</textsearchlabel>
            <titlefield>FiberRingID.RingName</titlefield>
            <fields>
                <field name="FiberRingID.RingName" alias="RingName"/>
                <field name="FiberRingID.FiberID" alias="FiberID"/>
            </fields>
            <orderbyfields>FiberRingID.RingName ASC</orderbyfields>
        </layer>
        <layer>
            <name>IRU Fiber</name>
            <url>http://vdi-standard103.lumosnet.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Type2CircuitsOffNet/AllType2MapCircuitsOffNet/MapServer/12</url>
            <expression>FiberRingID.RingName LIKE upper('%[value]%')</expression>
            <textsearchlabel>Search Ring ID</textsearchlabel>
            <titlefield>FiberRingID.RingName</titlefield>
            <fields>
                <field name="FiberRingID.RingName" alias="RingName"/>
                <field name="FPAIRUFiberMerge.FeatureID" alias="FeatureID"/>
            </fields>
            <orderbyfields>FiberRingID.RingName ASC</orderbyfields>
        </layer>
    </layers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not updating. Apparently the fact I was trying to use a joined table in the query was causing problems. I exported the joined table as it's own layer and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your service public? I would check the fields you are submitting the query to in your map services, make sure they are the same as your code.